# Trying to pass array and use foreach to send back multiple data

Tags: javascript, api, express, routes

I had getProductInfo orgianlly, as two parameters, where it would be (res, sku). but now I want to pass a set object with sku numbers and for-each res.send the data

```
const activeProductBank = new Set([6401728, 6430161, 6359222, 6368084]);

getProductInfo = (res) => {
    activeProductBank.forEach((SKU) => {
        bby.products(SKU, { show:'sku,name' })
        .then(function(data) {
            res.send(data);
        });
    })
};
```

also tried this

```
getProductInfo = (res) => {
    const allProductInfo = '';

    activeProductBank.forEach((SKU) => {
        bby.products(SKU, { show:'sku,name'})
        .then(function(data) {
            allProductInfo.concat(data);
        });
    })
    res.send(allProductInfo);
};
```

The error I get "app listening at http://localhost:3000
(node:25556) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Exceeded max retries"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a combination of `ASYNC / AWAIT` and `Promise.all` to populate the `allProductInfo` as expected.

The caveat with `ASYNC / AWAIT` is that you can only use ASYNC function inside an ASYNC function. More about it here https://javascript.info/async-await

`activeProductBank.map` will iterate over all your `activeProductBank` and returns an array of Promises which are then passed over to the `Promise.all` which then resolves after all the promises in the list are reolved.

[**Promise.all**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)

```
getProductInfo = async (res) => {

    const allProductInfo = Promise.all(
                                activeProductBank.map(SKU => bby.products(SKU, { show:'sku,name'}))
                            )
    
    res.send(allProductInfo);
};
```

Another approach is to use for..of loop and pushing the response of each productInfo one by one using the Await call like below

```
getProductInfo = async (res) => {
    let allProductInfo = [];

    for(let sku of allProductInfo) {
        const productInfo = await bby.products(sku, { show:'sku,name'});
        allProductInfo.push(productInfo);
    }
    
    res.send(allProductInfo);
};
```